# How/Why can you dispose something in another class?

Tags: java, libgdx

Why can you dispose a sprites texture like this: `sprite.getTexture().dispose();`

Don't you get the texture by value (a copy) because of java, wouldn't you just dispose the copy of the texture? Im misunderstanding something here.

Comment: In Java, a reference is essentially a pointer. So it's like a pointer passed by value, pointing at the same object. You only get a copy if someone explicitly wrote the method to manually instantiate a copy and return that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Sprite`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html) inherits from [`TextureRegion`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html) and [`TextureRegion.getTexture()`](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html) is implemented like:

```java
public Texture getTexture () {
        return texture;
}
```

So no, you don't get a copy but a reference to the sprite's texture. With calling `dispose()` you'd dispose the sprites texture.

Answer (score 0):

You will got references to objects in java, not values. But there is another reason why `dispose()` and its interface `Disposable` are utilized in libGDX. Some resources handled by libGDX (textures are among them) do not have to lie in JVM's scope. For example texture's pixmap can be on-heap or in video memory. You will release that resource by calling `dispose()`. And you should do it every time you no longer neeed that `Disposable` resource, to prevent leaks.